# Multiple databases syncing in Django

Tags: django, database

I previously had SQLite default database with Django and was using it for user authentication. I am building a CMS, hence I need to store images. So I added a PostgreSQL database in settings.py and created new models for images in models.py. How do I migrate these new changes to the newly created database? If I do

```
python manage.py migrate
```

the newly created models will be stored in SQLite database only right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify your databases in settings.py files like this :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
    'postgresql': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'myproject',
        'USER': 'myprojectuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Then, in your project folder, you can create a file named : **routersGlobal.py**

```
from django.conf import settings

class GlobalRouter(object):
    """
A router to control all database operations on models in the
auth application.
"""

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read auth models go to auth.
        """
        app_list = ('auth', 'admin', 'contenttypes', 'sessions',)

        if model._meta.app_label in app_list:
            return 'default' #According to database name sqlite3
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write auth models go to auth.
        """
        app_list = ('auth', 'admin', 'contenttypes', 'sessions',)
        if model._meta.app_label in app_list:
            return 'default'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in the auth app is involved.
        """
        app_list = ('auth', 'admin', 'contenttypes', 'sessions',)
        if obj1._meta.app_label in app_list and obj2._meta.app_label in app_list:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure the auth app only appears in the 'auth'
        database.
        """
        app_list = ('auth', 'admin', 'contenttypes', 'sessions',)

        if app_label in app_list:
            return db == 'default'
        return None
```

And you can create an other file which named : **routersLocal.py** file :

```
from django.conf import settings

class LocalRouter(object):
    """
A router to control all database operations on models in the
auth application.
"""

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read auth models go to auth.
        """
        app_list = ('YourNewApp',)

        if model._meta.app_label in app_list:
            return 'postgresql'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write auth models go to auth.
        """
        app_list = ('YourNewApp',)
        if model._meta.app_label in app_list:
            return 'postgresql'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in the auth app is involved.
        """
        app_list = ('YourNewApp',)
        if obj1._meta.app_label in app_list and obj2._meta.app_label in app_list:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure the auth app only appears in the 'auth'
        database.
        """
        app_list = ('YourNewApp',)

        if app_label in app_list:
            return db == 'postgresql'
        return None
```

And finally in settings.py file you have to specified redirections :

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['YourProjectName.routersLocal.LocalRouter', 'YourProjectName.routersGlobal.GlobalRouter']
```

Then, it should work and apply dissociate migrations

Comment: Is there any alternative? This code seems very cryptic and nothing makes sense to me. Thank you for the help.

Comment: If you want to use multiple databases, you have to implement this in your DJango project to my mind. But, you should think this kind of thing at the beginning of your project, not during the development phasis.